# Como trocar múltiplas telas no PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Estou tendo problemas com meu código atual utilizando a biblioteca do PySimpleGUI.

Basicamente quero fazer um sistema de múltiplas telas porem não tenho ideia de como fazer com que uma janela feche sem encerrar o programa.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

forca = agil = intel = presen = vigor = mov = np = XPP = insan = 0
vida = limite = san = limitesan = PE = limitePE = 50
limiteinsan = 12
nplimite = 14
pontos = 8



def tela_login():
    laylog = [
        [sg.Text('Usuário: ', key='usuario', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Input(key='usuariocampo', size=(20, 0))],
        [sg.Text('Senha:   ', key='senha', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.InputText(key='senhacampo', size=(20, 0), password_char='*')],
        [sg.Checkbox('Deseja ver a senha?', key='versenha', background_color='black')],
        [sg.Text(key='vazio', size=(20, 0), background_color='black')],
        [sg.Button('Confirmar', key='confirmalog', size=(0, 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Canvas(background_color='black', size=(65, 0)),
         sg.Button('Atualizar', key='update', size=(0, 0), button_color='black')],

    ]
    return sg.Window('Login', layout=laylog, background_color='black', finalize=True)

def tela_personagem():
    layout = [
        # nome, vida, sanidade, arquétipo, classe, nivel de personagem, idade, altura, profissão, zumbis, humanos

        [sg.Text('Nome: ', size=(0, 0), key='Nome', background_color='black'),
         sg.Input(size=(20, 1), key='texto', background_color='black', text_color='white')],

        [sg.Text('Arquétipo: ', size=(0, 0), key='NomeArq', background_color='black'),
         sg.InputOptionMenu(['Combatente', 'Especialista'], background_color='black', text_color='white')],

        [sg.Text('Classe: ', size=(0, 0), key='NomeCla', background_color='black'),
         sg.InputOptionMenu(['Comandante', 'Mercenário', 'Robusto', 'Mestre das lâminas', 'Artista Marcial',
                             'Atirador de elite', 'Infiltrador', 'Investigador', 'Socorrista'],
                            background_color='black', text_color='white')],

        [sg.Text('Nível de Personagem: ', size=(0, 0), key='NP', background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('<', key='npmenos', button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(np, size=(2, 0), key='Totalnp', background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('>', key='npmais', button_color='black'), sg.Text('/', background_color='black'),
         sg.Text(nplimite, key='Limitenp', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Text('XPP', background_color='black'), sg.Text('=', background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('<', key='xppmenos', button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(XPP, size=(3, 0), key='xpp', background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('>', key='xppmais', button_color='black')],

        [sg.Text('Idade: ', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.InputText(size=(2, 0), key='idade', background_color='black', text_color='white')],

        [sg.Text('Altura: ', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.InputText(size=(4, 0), key='altura', background_color='black', text_color='white')],

        [sg.Text('Profissão: ', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.InputText(size=(15, 0), key='profissao', background_color='black', text_color='white')],

        [sg.Text('Mortes: ', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Text('Zumbi: ', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.InputText(size=(4, 0), key='zumbi', background_color='black', text_color='white'),
         sg.Text('Humanos: ', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.InputText(size=(4, 0), key='humanos', background_color='black', text_color='white')],

        [sg.Text(f'Vida:       ', size=(0, 0), key='Vida', background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('<', key='menosvida', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(f'{vida}', size=(3, 0), key='Total', background_color='black'), sg.Text('/', background_color='black'),
         sg.Text(f'{vida}  ', key='Limite', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('>', key='maisvida', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('+1 limite', key='+1 limite', size=(0, 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('-1 limite', key='-1 limite', size=(0, 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('Igualar', key='igual', size=(0, 0), button_color='black')],

        [sg.Text(f'Sanidade:', size=(0, 0), key='Sanidade', background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('<', key='menossan', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(san, size=(3, 0), key='Totalsan', background_color='black'), sg.Text('/', background_color='black'),
         sg.Text(f'{limite} ', key='Limitesan', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('>', key='maissan', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('+1 limite', key='+1 limitesan', size=(0, 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('-1 limite', key='-1 limitesan', size=(0, 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('Igualar', key='igualsan', size=(0, 0), button_color='black')],

        [sg.Text(f'Insanidade:', size=(0, 0), key='Insanidade', background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('<', key='menosinsan', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(insan, size=(3, 0), key='Totalinsan', background_color='black'),
         sg.Text('/', background_color='black'),
         sg.Text(f'{limiteinsan} ', key='Limiteinsan', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('>', key='maisinsan', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('Igualar', key='igualinsan', size=(0, 0), button_color='black')],

        [sg.Text('PE: ', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('<', key='menospe', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(PE, size=(3, 0), key='Totalpe', background_color='black'), sg.Text('/', background_color='black'),
         sg.Text(f'{limitePE} ', key='Limitepe', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('>', key='maispe', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('+1 limite', key='+1 limitepe', size=(0, 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('-1 limite', key='-1 limitepe', size=(0, 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('Igualar', key='igualpe', size=(0, 0), button_color='black')],

        [sg.Text('Dinheiro: R$', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.InputText(size=(7, 0), background_color='black', text_color='white')],

        [sg.Text('Defesa', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Text('Física', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.InputText(size=(2, 0), background_color='black', text_color='white'),
         sg.Text('Balística', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.InputText(size=(2, 0), background_color='black', text_color='white')],

        [sg.Text('Proeficiências', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.InputOptionMenu(['Armas Furtivas', 'Armas Militares', 'Armas Longas',
                             'Armas Comuns', 'Armas Improvisadas'], background_color='black', text_color='white'),
         sg.InputOptionMenu(['Armas Furtivas', 'Armas Militares', 'Armas Longas',
                             'Armas Comuns', 'Armas Improvisadas'], background_color='black', text_color='white')
         ],

        [sg.Text('\nAtributos: ', background_color='black')],

        # Atributos:

        [sg.Text(' Força:         ', key='força', size=(0, 0), pad=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('<', key='forçamenos', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(forca, key='hab>', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('>', key='forçamais', size=(1, 1), button_color='black')],

        [sg.Text(' Agilidade:    ', key='agil', size=(0, 0), pad=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('<', key='agilmenos', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(agil, key='atributoagil', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('>', key='agilmais', size=(1, 1), button_color='black')],

        [sg.Text(' Inteligência: ', key='intel', size=(0, 0), pad=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('<', key='intelmenos', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(intel, key='habintel', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('>', key='intelmais', size=(1, 1), button_color='black')],

        [sg.Text(' Presença: ', key='presen', size=(0, 0), pad=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('<', key='presenmenos', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(presen, key='atributopresen', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('>', key='presenmais', size=(1, 1), button_color='black')],

        [sg.Text(' Vigor: ', key='vigor', size=(0, 0), pad=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('<', key='vigormenos', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(vigor, key='atributovigor', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('>', key='vigormais', size=(1, 1), button_color='black')],

        [sg.Text(' Movimentação: ', key='mov', size=(0, 0), pad=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button('< ', key='movmenos', size=(1, 1), pad=((0, 0), 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Text(f'{mov} ', key='atributomov', size=(2, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Button(' >', key='movmais', size=(1, 1), button_color='black')],

        [sg.Text(f'Pontos restantes: {pontos}', key='ponto', size=(0, 0), background_color='black'),
         sg.Canvas(background_color='black', size=(200, 0)), sg.Text('v1.5', background_color='black')],

        [sg.Button('Sair', key='pushButton', size=(0, 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('Habilidades', key='habButton', size=(0, 0), button_color='black'),
         sg.Button('Inventário', key='invButton', size=(0, 0), button_color='black')]

    ]
    return sg.Window('Ficha de Jodador', layout=layout, background_color='black', finalize=True)

def tela_habilidades():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Teste', size=(0, 0)), sg.Button('Fechar', key='FecharHab', button_color='black')]

    ]
    return sg.Window('Habilidades', layout=layout, background_color='black', finalize=True)

def tela_inventario():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Teste', background_color='black')]

    ]
    return sg.Window('Inventário', layout=layout, background_color='black', finalize=True)


# janela
janelalog, janelaficha, janelahab, janelainven = tela_login(), None, None, None
# janela = sg.Window('Ficha de jogador', layout, size=(400, 400))

# eventos
while True:
    janela, evento, valores = sg.read_all_windows()

    # login

    if janela == janelalog and evento == 'update':
        if valores['versenha']:
            janelalog['senhacampo'].update(password_char='')
        else:
            janelalog['senhacampo'].update(password_char='*')

    # fechar o programa

    if janela == janelalog and evento == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    # proxima tela

    if janela == janelalog and evento == 'confirmalog':
        if valores['usuariocampo'] == 'novo' and valores['senhacampo'] == '12345':
            janelaficha = tela_personagem()
            janelalog.hide()
        else:
            janelalog['vazio'].update('Usuário ou Senha invalída!')

    if janela == janelaficha and evento == 'habButton':
        janelaficha.hide()
        janelaficha = tela_habilidades()
        
    if janela == janelahab and evento == 'FecharHab':
        print('teste')
        janelahab.hide()
        janelaficha.un_hide()
        janelahab = tela_personagem()

    if janela == janelaficha and evento == 'invButton':
        janelaficha = tela_inventario()




    # eventos na tela de ficha

    if evento == 'npmenos' and np > 0:
        np -= 1
        janela['Totalnp'].update(np)

    if evento == 'npmais':
        np += 1
        janela['Totalnp'].update(np)

    if evento == 'npmais' and np >= nplimite:
        np = nplimite
        janela['Totalnp'].update(np)

    if evento == 'xppmais':
        XPP += 5
        janela['xpp'].update(XPP)

    if evento == 'xppmenos' and XPP > 0:
        XPP -= 5
        janela['xpp'].update(XPP)

    # eventos de atributos

    # eventos de força

    if evento == 'forçamais' and pontos > 0:
        forca += 1
        pontos -= 1
        janela['hab>'].update(forca)
        janela['ponto'].update(f'Pontos restantes: {pontos}')

    if evento == 'forçamenos' and forca > 0:
        forca -= 1
        pontos += 1
        janela['hab>'].update(forca)
        janela['ponto'].update(f'Pontos restantes: {pontos}')

    # eventos de agilidade

    if evento == 'agilmais' and pontos > 0:
        agil += 1
        pontos -= 1
        janela['atributoagil'].update(agil)
        janela['ponto'].update(f'Pontos restantes: {pontos}')

    if evento == 'agilmenos' and agil > 0:
        agil -= 1
        pontos += 1
        janela['atributoagil'].update(agil)
        janela['ponto'].update(f'Pontos restantes: {pontos}')

    # eventos de inteligência

    if evento == 'intelmais' and pontos > 0:
        intel += 1
        pontos -= 1
        janela['habintel'].update(intel)
        janela['ponto'].update(f'Pontos restantes: {pontos}')

    if evento == 'intelmenos' and intel > 0:
        intel -= 1
        pontos += 1
        janela['habintel'].update(intel)
        janela['ponto'].update(f'Pontos restantes: {pontos}')

    # eventos de presença

    if evento == 'presenmais' and pontos > 0:
        presen += 1
        pontos -= 1
        janela['atributopresen'].update(presen)
        janela['ponto'].update(f'Pontos restantes: {pontos}')

    if evento == 'presenmenos' and presen > 0:
        presen -= 1
        pontos += 1
        janela['atributopresen'].update(presen)
        janela['ponto'].update(f'Pontos restantes: {pontos}')

    # eventos de vigor

    if evento == 'vigormais' and pontos > 0:
        vigor += 1
        pontos -= 1
        janela['atributovigor'].update(vigor)
        janela['ponto'].update(f'Pontos restantes: {pontos}')

    if evento == 'vigormenos' and vigor > 0:
        vigor -= 1
        pontos += 1
        janela['atributovigor'].update(vigor)
        janela['ponto'].update(f'Pontos restantes: {pontos}')

    # eventos de movimentação

    if evento == 'movmais':
        mov += 1
        janela['atributomov'].update(mov)

    if evento == 'movmenos' and mov > 0:
        mov -= 1
        janela['atributomov'].update(mov)

    # eventos de vida

    if evento == '+1 limite':
        limite += 1
        janela['Limite'].update(limite)

    if evento == '-1 limite' and limite > 0:
        limite -= 1
        janela['Limite'].update(limite)

    if evento == 'maisvida':
        vida += 1
        janela['Total'].update(vida)

    if evento == 'menosvida' and vida > 0:
        vida -= 1
        janela['Total'].update(vida)

    if evento == 'maisvida' and vida >= limite:
        vida = limite
        janela['Total'].update(vida)

    if evento == '-1 limite' and vida >= limite:
        vida = limite
        janela['Total'].update(vida)

    if evento == 'igual':
        vida = limite
        janela['Total'].update(vida)

    # eventos de sanidade

    if evento == '+1 limitesan':
        limitesan += 1
        janela['Limitesan'].update(limitesan)

    if evento == '-1 limitesan' and limitesan > 0:
        limitesan -= 1
        janela['Limitesan'].update(limitesan)

    if evento == 'maissan':
        san += 1
        janela['Totalsan'].update(san)

    if evento == 'menossan' and san > 0:
        san -= 1
        janela['Totalsan'].update(san)

    if evento == 'maissan' and san >= limitesan:
        san = limitesan
        janela['Totalsan'].update(san)

    if evento == '-1 limitesan' and san >= limitesan:
        san = limitesan
        janela['Totalsan'].update(san)

    if evento == 'igualsan':
        san = limitesan
        janela['Totalsan'].update(san)

    # eventos de insanidade

    if evento == 'maisinsan':
        insan += 1
        janela['Totalinsan'].update(insan)

    if evento == 'menosinsan' and insan > 0:
        insan -= 1
        janela['Totalinsan'].update(insan)

    if evento == 'maisinsan' and insan >= limiteinsan:
        insan = limiteinsan
        janela['Totalinsan'].update(insan)

    if evento == '-1 limiteinsan' and insan >= limiteinsan:
        insan = limiteinsan
        janela['Totalinsan'].update(insan)

    if evento == 'igualinsan':
        insan = limiteinsan
        janela['Totalinsan'].update(insan)

    # eventos de PE

    if evento == '+1 limitepe':
        limitePE += 1
        janela['Limitepe'].update(limitePE)

    if evento == '-1 limitepe' and limitePE > 0:
        limitePE -= 1
        janela['Limitepe'].update(limitePE)

    if evento == 'maispe':
        PE += 1
        janela['Totalpe'].update(PE)

    if evento == 'menospe' and PE > 0:
        PE -= 1
        janela['Totalpe'].update(PE)

    if evento == 'maispe' and PE >= limitePE:
        PE = limitePE
        janela['Totalpe'].update(PE)

    if evento == '-1 limitepe' and PE >= limitePE:
        PE = limitePE
        janela['Totalpe'].update(PE)

    if evento == 'igualpe':
        PE = limitePE
        janela['Totalpe'].update(PE)

    # eventos de saída

    if janela == janelaficha and evento == 'pushButton':
        break

    if evento == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

Answer (score -4):

Você pode utilizar janela.hide() e janela.un_hide() para abrir ou fechar janelas sem encerrar o programa.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).